# Combine Sky texture with other layers with alpha channel

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes, transparency, render-layers, layers

I have a scene with two different render layers. The first one is a background with Sky texture. The second one is some images of mountains with alpha channel. For second layer I need Transparency to have an alpha channel to get a background with Sky texture as a sky. The thing is if I enable transparency, the first layer renders as one total alpha channel. If I disable transparency the second layer renders without alpha channel and I can't apply the first layer as sky because the second layer overlaps it by solid black. if I render them separately I lose one of them. [image: Layers rendered separately] [image: both layers rendered with transparency] [image: Both layers rendered without transparency] [image: Overlaping] [image: Attachement to the first answer]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the layer with the landscape and the clouds does not have an alpha channel (that is why the alpha over operation does not work). In the film section enable "transparent"

[image]

To use the background set on the world settings enable "environment" on the layer passes.

[image]

Then connect the environment socket of the rendered layer to the alpha over node to use as background:

[image]

Comment: You can see on some screenshots landscape has alpha. I can check use background on the landscape layer to have sky texture bu I want to compose them in the compositor separately.

Comment: Wait I think I missed something.

Comment: Thank you. Problem solved. I thought that check environment in passes and in layers is the same.

Answer (score 1):

Use node "Set Alpha" for completely removing transparency:

[image]

Comment: If I use Set Alpha on environment layer it just goes black. Doesn't seem to have any sky texture.